# Can you set background colour of background image CSS?

Tags: html, css

bit of a strange request but I was wondering if it is possible to set the background colour of a background image applied to a div? I know you can set the background colour of an `<img />`.

I've tried:

`background: #FFFFFF url(image.png) no-repeat bottom center;`

Which just changes the colour of the div that the image is applied to.

Thanks for any help at all

*edit, added image to better explain issue:

[image]

The last pod in this right hand nav has the background image/shadow applied, i would ideally like to give this shadow a background color so that it blends in with the background of the page rather than being white like the containing div.

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to achieve with an example?

Comment: So you wish the background color to be no larger than your background image and not fill the entire space right? If this is the case then the answer is no :(. You can use another div inside your container to be exactly as big as your image.

Comment: @Caelea thats exactly it. I guess i'll try your suggestion

Comment: I guess i could take to photoshop and just colour the transparent/background region of the image the colour I want as a possible solution but it seems really messy. Adding another div take up additional space and make the container a bit taller than it should be. I'll update my question with a screen shot of the look im trying to achieve

Comment: In this case just place your background image outside your div, let's say -5px or whatever your image height is. You can master the rest of the div height by css. The last background will merge with the gray color of your site, while the other ones will remain white. I think you'll also need to place your divs with `margin-top:-5px` and increase the top padding.

Comment: I've tried this but the height of the nav is not fixed and has a min-height so as to expand as new pods are added, this is a kentico site and the pods are webparts that can be freely added/removed. If i place the image as a background on the containing nav div it still does the same thing since the containers bg color is white (like the pods). I've tried making the image an actual `<img>` element and placing it outside of the div and the using position relative to place it correctly but the images takes up space in the container and makes it slightly taller than it needs to be..

Comment: ... and i cant resize the height as it expands to fit the content within

Comment: @Duane Can you post the link to your site?

Comment: It's in development at the moment. I can post a pastebin of the markup for the control if that works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If those are all a single image (it's usually considered bad practice to have content text in images, btw), then I'd recommend using your image editor to make the space between the blocks transparent (don't forget to include the shadows, so they have alpha transparency over the correct color, instead of over white). That will allow the HTML element's background color to show through.

That said, I would personally make those blocks into regular text and HTML blocks (so the only images are the decoration images on the right hand side of each), which you can easily add the shadow to with `box-shadow`.

The `box-shadow` property is, by nature, transparent other than where the shadow itself is. This means that its "background" will always be what is underneath it (in simple cases, this would be the background of the containing element, though it can also be text or images, if the element with `box-shadow` is on top of it).

Check out my jsFiddle to see what I'm talking about (it's a quick one, so it doesn't look exactly like the effect you're going for, but that effect is possible with a little creativity): http://jsfiddle.net/DXrk6/1/

Answer (score 0):

Use

`background: #FFFFFF url(image.png) no-repeat bottom center;`

it will fill up the background of the element (div, ...) with the image.png and fill the rest with the color #FFFFFF